# Missing --create_source_map option for Closure Compiler Service API

Tags: api, google-closure-compiler, source-maps

I'm using Closure Compiler Service API to get JavaScript compiledCode. For debugging purposes on live environments I may need to have an option to get the source maps from same response if possible, similar to command line option *--create_source_map*: https://developers.google.com/closure/compiler/faq

Is closure compiler service API able to do that too? I could not find any arguments in this regard https://developers.google.com/closure/compiler/docs/api-ref

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The API does not currently support this.  It would be good to file a issue https://github.com/google/closure-compiler but the team has not really been investing in the API.  Keep in mind the API service isn't really suitable for production services as it doesn't provide any uptime guarantees or any guarantees at all really (having per minute/hour/day throttling per user and can contain breaking changes whenever the Closure Compiler is released).

Comment: I understand that. Thank you! Actually I used standalone compiler to generate the map file then uploaded to production server. However I may have found a limitation i.e., my uncompressed file already had some minified JS code and after compressing using Google Closure through command line and uploading to server I realized that Chrome Debug Console did not match correctly the breakpoints, though map file and uncompressed file were loaded. Will have further tests to validate that using a clean/uncompressed code against minified version using local compiler is going to match correctly for debug.